# RegEx matches fine, but HTML output is bad

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular expression, taken from PHP.net to capture [code][/code] tags.

```
function code_highlight($code)
{
    return $code = preg_replace_callback('#\[code]((?:[^[]|\[(?!/?code])|(?R))+)\[/code]#', 'code_highlight_callback', $code);
}
```

My callback function is:

```
function code_highlight_callback($matches)
{
    return "<pre class='highlighted_code'>" . $matches[0] . "</pre>";
}
```

If I echo the line with `htmlentities()` instead of returning it, I get something along the lines of:

```
<pre class='highlighted_code'>
    [code]int main()</div> 
    <div>{</div> 
    <div>}</div> 
    <div>[/code]
</pre>
```

All appears to be fine as far as the regular expression is concerned. However, if I output the return value, the source code ends up looking like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <pre class="highlighted_code">[code]int main()</pre>
    </div>
    <div>{</div>
    <div>}</div>
    <div>[/code] </div>
</div>
```

Why is the PRE tag getting moved and cut short? The regex is clearly capturing the entire [code] [/code] section of the string, yet something, somewhere, is messing it right up and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why not use PHP's native [BBCode](http://php.net/bbcode)?

Comment: BBCode is not "native", it's an extension that may not be available.

Comment: It is just an "index" issue. Use matches[1] instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking your result through the browser's DOM inspector? If so, it will have automatically "corrected" your tags to close in the right order. I think your `code_highlight_callback` should be:

```
function code_highlight_callback($matches) {
    return "<pre class='highlighted_code'>".htmlspecialchars($matches[0])."</pre>";
}
```

Comment: If I use `htmlspecialchars($matches[0])`, it fixes the issue and my pre tags work as they should do. However, now all the HTML is showing up as output which I don't want. In my `code_highlight_callback` function I actually call a third function to add `<span></span>` tags around about 100 keywords (which works perfectly and without error--I removed it for brevity and the fact that I was debugging without using it). I don't get this highlighting effect now, all I get is actual HTML as output such as `<span style='etc'>blah</span>`. I don't fully understand why the `</pre>` is getting moved?

Comment: You have an `</div>` in there. This is closing the container `<div>` and therefore the `<pre>` as well. Move your keyword function somewhere after the `[code]` function.

Comment: I actually don't have a `</div>` in there, though. The browser is adding it in for some reason. I have this in a DB, exactly as you see it: `<div>[code]int main()</div><div>{</div><div>}</div><div>[/code]</div>`, then in the browser the unnecessary closing `</div>` is being added. Is this normal behaviour? Why is the browser doing this? I'm also running the code through HTML Purifier, but have commented out that line for now (it makes no difference). Building a rich-text editor with [code][/code] support is harder than it sounds.